# Creating a new table in database with description from existing table as an input

Tags: c++, sql, oracle, qt, qt4

I have written a QT GUI application that connects to an Oracle Database and performs query and shows the output in a QTableView.

```
QString host_name=ui->lineHostName->text();
QString db_name=ui->lineDatabaseName->text();
QString user_name=ui->lineUserName->text();
QString pass_word=ui->linePassword->text();
QString port_no=ui->linePortNumber->text();

QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QOCI");

db.setHostName(host_name);
db.setDatabaseName(db_name);
db.setUserName(user_name);
db.setPassword(pass_word);
db.setPort(port_no.toInt());

QString MyQuery = ui->lineQuery->text();
db.open();
QSqlQuery query(MyQuery,db);

if(query.exec())
{
    this->model=new QSqlQueryModel();
    model->setQuery(MyQuery);

    ui->tableViewOra->setModel(model);
}
```

After running the program, I tried to use this (as a substitute of the DESC )---

```
SELECT
column_name "Name",
nullable "Null?",
concat(concat(concat(data_type,'('),data_length),')') "Type"
FROM user_tab_columns
WHERE table_name='my_table_number_one';
```

And the column names, null parameter and data type was shown on the QTableView

Now my question is, can I use this information in the QTableView to create another table with same Column names and data type ??? (Basically creating a copy of my queried table table).

**EDIT**

After suggestions i tried modifying with---

```
QString query_to_replicate;
query_to_replicate=QString("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE %1 AS %2").arg("AJ_REPLACEMENT_TESTING").arg(ui->lineEdit->text());
QSqlQuery query_second(query_to_replicate,db);

if(query_second.exec())
{
    ui->r_pop_Button->setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);}");

    this->model_relocate=new QSqlQueryModel();
    model_relocate->setQuery(query_second);
    ui->tableView2->setModel(model_relocate);
    while (model_relocate->canFetchMore())
        model_relocate->fetchMore();
    qDebug()<<QDateTime::currentDateTime()<<"Query SUCCESS ";
    db.close();
}
```

now it worked twice, without throwing errors and created replicated copies in the oracle database (I used different names for replicated table before building).

But after running successfully twice, it seized replicating. Situation is completely clueless. I am not getting any errors during build / compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by using CREATE TABLE AS SELECT:

```
QString sql = "CREATE TABLE %1 AS %2"
    .arg(yourNewTableName)
    .arg(ui->lineQuery->text());
// and execute this sql code on your QSqlDatabase as you do it above
```

It will create new table, with name from "yourNewTableName" variable and copy data from select query to new table.

Code update:

```
QString query_to_replicate;
query_to_replicate=QString("CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE %1 AS %2").arg("AJ_REPLACEMENT_TESTING").arg(ui->lineEdit->text());
QSqlQuery query_second(query_to_replicate,db); // query will be executed there! weird, but...

if (query_second.lastError().isValid())
{
    qDebug() << query_second.lastError().text(); // error happens
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Table created successfully";
}
```

Also, you must `#include <QSqlError>` in the top of file, to use QtSql errors.

Comment: what are the arguments needed here ??? is this the final syntax of QString sql = ...... declaration ???

Comment: QString query_to_replicate;
    query_to_replicate=QString("CREATE TABLE %1 AS %2").arg(AJ_REPLICATED).arg(ui->lineEdit->text());
    QSqlQuery query2(query_to_replicate,db);


it is showing error that /home/aj/MY_QT_WORK/replicate_populate/mainwindow.cpp:95: error: ‘AJ_REPLICATED’ was not declared in this scope

Comment: AJ_REPLICATED must be a string, contains new table name, i.e.
QString AJ_REPLICATED = "myNewTable";

Comment: but it threw an error during build time... can you guide me what is the proper syntax to write it in the code ???

Comment: i have edited the present situation in my question. please refer to it. thank you for your suggestion, it worked two times but now it is not working. i dont have any idea how is this possible for a code to function twice and then not working at all. Right now I am not getting any kind of errors during build / compile time.

Comment: First of all, look at:
QSqlQuery query_second(query_to_replicate,db);
if(query_second.exec()) - this will execute query twice, because documentation says: "QSqlQuery::QSqlQuery(const QString & query = QString(), QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase())
Constructs a QSqlQuery object using the SQL query and the database db. If db is not specified, or is invalid, the application's default database is used. **If query is not an empty string, it will be executed**." I'll update my answer with code

Comment: your code update worked... actually CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE could not get passed successfully... So I used CREATE TABLE only... thank you...